# Can I increase the decrease value from a for loop in python?

Tags: python

How do I increase the decrease value every loop in for loop ?.

Example:
from decrease by -7 -> -6 -> -4 -> -1.

current code:

```
for i in range(4,0,-1):
    Dev.step(2)
    if i == 1 or i == 3:
        Dev.turnLeft()
        Dev.step(i)
        Dev.step(-i)
        Dev.turnRight()
    else:
        Dev.turnRight()
        Dev.step(i+4)
        Dev.step(-i-4)
        Dev.turnLeft()
```

Comment: You can change the `-1` third argument to `-2` or `-3` etc.

Comment: `b = b + i + 1` ?

Comment: Please don't completely change the question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: Can I do it without a variable?

Comment: You cannot change the *step* value mid-loop

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on comment not to use a separate variable
You can use the loop variable i to determine the current decrement value.

```
# Loop from 4 to 0, using the current value of i as the decrement value
for i in range(4,0,-i):
    Dev.step(2)
    if i == 1 or i == 3:
        Dev.turnLeft()
        Dev.step(i)
        Dev.step(-i)
        Dev.turnRight()
    else:
        Dev.turnRight()
        Dev.step(i+4)
        Dev.step(-i-4)
        Dev.turnLeft()
```

Comment: Can I do it without a variable?

Comment: I updated the answer based on your comment

Comment: @plshelp did this solve your issue?

Comment: no, I change the issue